# Mongo lookup for embedded data / embedded arrays with unknown depth

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a data structure that has relationships at various (unknown/dynamic) levels of nesting, for example it might look something like this:

```json
{
  _id: "652be26ec569bba673fa3539"
  a: [
    {_id: "652be3616dbd4840c17adf1f", noteIds: ["652be3c5090a2b22c1d35a2d", "652be3d0ba2da5cb7ddf36ac"]},
    {_id: "652be3f0d02743f9059e583d", noteIds: ["652be401bb0100c78a55ce3a", "652be40947bcd5275d272d46"]}
  ]
  b: {
    c: {
      noteIds: ["652be47a0994896f73ce4c48", "652be481cef028a036e09646"],
    },
  },
}
```

I also have the paths for these relationships ie `a.noteIds` and `b.c.noteIds`, but these paths are dynamic and not baked into the code.

Is there a way in mongo to perform a `$lookup` that will join at the leaf nodes, ie resulting in something like:

```json
{
  _id: "652be26ec569bba673fa3539"
  a: [
    {_id: "652be3616dbd4840c17adf1f", notes: [{_id: "652be3c5090a2b22c1d35a2d", ...}, {_id: "652be3d0ba2da5cb7ddf36ac", ...}]},
    {_id: "652be3f0d02743f9059e583d", notes: [{_id: "652be401bb0100c78a55ce3a", ...}, {_id: "652be40947bcd5275d272d46", ...}]}
  ]
  b: {
    c: {
      notes: [{_id: "652be47a0994896f73ce4c48", ...}, {_id: "652be481cef028a036e09646", ...}],
    },
  },
}
```

I've been poring over the documentation and trying to come up with solutions for days but can't seem to find an answer. In particular, while I can get this to work for nested objects and nested object paths using set/project - arrays keep tripping me up, because all the array operators seem to require knowing how deeply nested the array is to operate against.

Comment: I don't think there is a generic way for recursing nested structure for dynamic depth level. Consider refactoring your schema to store the entries as individual documents and use `$graphLookup` to reconstruct your recursive structure.

Comment: Thanks ray, unfortunately refactoring the schema is not an option for me.

Comment: I think you will then need to resort to using `$function` or application level code to process the recursive structure then

Comment: Here's a start - `$function` is used to discover all the `"noteIds"`.  Another somewhat similar `$function` is needed to recurse again and populate `"notes"`. https://mongoplayground.net/p/3Hka1xqMwju